# Facebook page integration doesn't validate

Tags: html, facebook, w3c-validation

The code that Facebook provides for website integration is: `<meta property="fb:page_id" content="<pageid>" />` However, this doesn't validate. Would it still work if I enclose the tag in comments like so? `<!--<meta property="fb:page_id" content="<pageid>" />-->`

Why didn't they just use the `name` attribute instead of `property`?

Note that I am using HTML5 (`<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `<!--<meta property="fb:page_id" content="<pageid>" />-->` validates and it seems to work.

Comment: When you do that, the fb linter gives warnings: "Required Property Missing..."